# Is it possible to factor $(c+1)(c-\frac32)+1=0$ without expanding $(c+1)(c-\frac32)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I have the equation $(c+1)(c-\frac32)+1=0$ and I'm trying to factor it without expanding $(c+1)(c-\frac32)$. I tried multiplying by $2$ to get rid of the fraction:

$$(c+1)(2c-3)+2=0$$
$$(c+1)(2c-3)+\frac25\times[2(c+1)-(2c-3)]=0$$
As you can see, I managed to make $2$ by using $c+1$ and $2c-3$. But I'm not sure if this helps.

Comment: What is the original problem? If you factorised too early, there might be a quicker way.

Comment: @TobyMak During solving a problem I got this equation. And I'm trying to factor it with the unusual method I mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, but what is the original problem?

Comment: @TobyMak It is not relevant to this post but if you want: " Find the value of $c$ so that $y=c-x^2$ is the answer of the following differential equation: $y'=(x^2+y+1)(x^2+y-\frac32)+1-2x$" .

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. I think you have to expand.

Comment: Why not expand it though?

Comment: @Paul Having some fun with algebra!

Comment: Fair enough so :)

Comment: the constants are $1$ and $-3/2$ so $[1 - (-3/2)]/2 = 5/4$. So you can write them as $(c - 1/4 + 5/4)$ and $(c - 1/4 - 5/4)$

Comment: I've already answered using your method, but it's nice you came up with the idea yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer:

$$((c - 1/4) + 5/4)((c - 1/4) - 5/4)) + 1 = 0$$
$$\implies (c-1/4)^2 - 25/16 + 1 = 0$$
$$\implies (c-1/4)^2 = 9/16$$
$$\implies c-1/4 = 3/4, -3/4 \implies c = 1, -\frac 12$$

This is just completing the square, which is made easier by the two brackets in $(c+1)(c-3/2)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\begin{cases}c+1=-\frac{1}{a}\\c-\frac 32=a\end{cases}&\implies a+\frac1a=-\frac 52\\
&\implies a^2+\frac 52 a+1=0\\
&\implies a\in\left\{-\frac 12,-2\right\}\ \\ &\implies c\in\left\{1,-\frac 12\right\}.\end{align}$$